# Passing a guid to SAP OData service in UI5

Tags: odata, sapui5

i have a read operation on an OData Set in which i pass the key. If the key is a string all works fine, but now we switched from String as key datatype to guid as data type and the read call doesn't work anymore. I receive always BAD Request 400.

Here the solution with the String parameter, which works.

```
var oModel = this.getView().getModel();
var someKey = "Key 1";
  oModel.read("/SomeSet('" + someKey + "')", {
    urlParameters: {"$expand":"SomeItemToExpand"},
    success: function (oData, oResponse) {
      sap.m.MessageToast.show("Read successfulf");              
    },
    error: function (onError) {
      sap.m.MessageBox.error("Error reading");
    }
});
```

How to pass a guid? I tried:

```
oModel.read("/SomeSet(guid'" + someKey + "')"
```

but dows not work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Create Entity Path Dynamically in UI5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46954621/how-to-create-entity-path-dynamically-in-ui5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured it out the best way pass a guid is:

```
oModel.read("/SomeSet(SomeKey=guid\'" + someKey + "\')", {
```

SomeKey= is the key name and this part is optional.

Comment: You should try to use createKey instead. If that key ever changes of type, your app logic still works, e.g.: `oModel.read(oModel.createKey("SomeSet", { SomeKey: someKey }))`