# How to create OData V2 entity path dynamically in UI5?

Tags: javascript, odata, sapui5

I want to update a table populated with OData service. I am using this approach:

```js
oModel.update("/Products(999)", data, {/*...*/});
```

I have the selected index stored in a variable (`myVar1`) and I need to pass that variable to the path string. The problem is `Products(999)` - this is working with the hard coded row but how to replace `999` with a variable?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Create the path dynamically via the [API `createKey`](https://sdk.openui5.org/api/sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel#methods/createKey) from the V2 ODataModel:

```js
const path = myODataV2Model.createKey("/Products", {
  // Key(s) and value(s) of that entity set
  "ProductID": myVar1, // with the value 999 for example
  "AnotherKeyProperty": "...",
});
myODataV2Model.update(path/*, ...*/); // applies also to .remove
```

Compared to concatenating strings for the path manually, `createKey` offers the following advantages:

- It outputs the key value always in the correct format corresponding to the [EDM type](https://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-2-0/overview/#AbstractTypeSystem) of the given property (using [`ODataUtils.formatValue`](https://sdk.openui5.org/api/sap.ui.model.odata.ODataUtils#methods/sap.ui.model.odata.ODataUtils.formatValue) internally). **E.g.:** If `ProductID` has the type `Edm.Int64`, UI5 appends the character `"l"` in the [output string](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/41f2655cd0b475e6c4a9c2739f2906f5abffdde0/src/sap.ui.core/src/sap/ui/model/odata/ODataUtils.js#L544-L612) aligning with the *OData specification*: `"999"` → `"999l"`
- It makes sure that all keys are encoded according to the URI standard (using `encodeURIComponent`<sup>[api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent)</sup> internally). **E.g.:** `ProductID='sp ace'` → `ProductID='sp%20ace'`
- It outputs the key value**s** always in the correct order no matter which backend system serves the metadata. Given the same metadata definition, it is possible that one system serves the metadata with keys in different orders than others. In such cases, if keys are just concatenated manually, the app would fail horribly throwing vague errors when it's transported to the system serving different key orders.

---

### Note

Since `createKey` relies on the information from the service metadata, the API should be performed after the `$metadata` is loaded. For this, the [promise based API `metadataLoaded`](https://sdk.openui5.org/api/sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel#methods/metadataLoaded) can be used.

```js
myODataV2Model.metadataLoaded(true).then(/*createKey*/);
```

Answer (score 0):

use the javascript concatenation operator `+` to merge the value of the variable into the url string:

```
var sIndex = "123";
oModel.update("/Products(" + sIndex + ")", oData, {success: mySuccessHandler, error: myErrorHandler});
```

by the way: numeric types convert hereby automatically into strings.