# Eslint : sap-no-ui5-prop-warning

Tags: sapui5, eslint

I want to remove the ESLint warnings.
I got `sap-no-ui5-prop-warning` because I used `this.getModel().oData["ProductSet('" + sId+ "')"].Matricule`. But when I use the function `getData()`, it returns null.

Do you have a suggestion how to fix this?

Comment: Instead of fighting symptoms (disabling the eslint rule), fix the [actual _cause_](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54554635/5846045).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the [docs](https://help.sap.com/viewer/825270ffffe74d9f988a0f0066ad59f0/Cloud/en-US/4093e3188b884ff0aa2c58fef7fcc97b.html). It's simple.

```js
/* eslint-disable sap-no-ui5base-prop */

...some code false positives

/* eslint-enable sap-no-ui5base-prop */
```

Btw `getData()` for ODataModel is deprecated.
You can use `getProperty("/")` instead. It'll give you the root level of your data.

Answer (score 0):

> Actually I use it like this `this.getModel().oData["ProductSet('" + sId+ "')"].Matricule`

Please do **not** disable the ESLint setting `sap-no-ui5-prop-warning` for cases like above. The way how the property is accessed goes highly against the conventions and JS coding guidelines.

> ### [JavaScript Code Issues](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/030fcd14963048218488048f407f8f34)
>
> #### Don't use methods or properties that are not public
>
> Don't use or override "private" methods or properties. (...) Always double check in the API Reference. If UI5 changes the implementation in a future release, your code will break if you fail to follow this guideline.

---

In order to access the value properly, make use of **available APIs** - preferably those  returning *context* such as `createBindingContext`<sup>[[api]](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel/methods/createBindingContext)</sup> or `getBindingContext`<sup>[[api]](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.base.ManagedObject/methods/getBindingContext)</sup>:

```js
createProductContext: function(productId /*, ...*/) {
  const myODataModel = /*...*/;
  const path = myODataModel.createKey("/ProductSet", {
    ProductID: productId, // See https://stackoverflow.com/a/47016070/5846045
  });
  myODataModel.createBindingContext(path, this.handleProductContext.bind(this));
},

handleProductContext: function(context) {
  if (!context) {
    return; // error - Context couldn't be created
  }
  const matricule = context.getProperty("Matricule"); // <-- Access property value
  // ...
},
```

If the binding context is already available:

```js
someMethod: function() {
  const context = this.byId("thatControlHavingODataBound").getBindingContext(/*modelName*/);
  this.handleProductContext(context);
},
```

Accessing property via a context ensures that the data is already available on the client-side in contrast to `myModel.getProperty()`.