# How to pass a key field as variable instead of hard-coded key value to OData operation?

Tags: sapui5

I am calling the GetEntity OData `read` method from the SAP UI5 view controller and passing a key value in the request URL. I am getting the proper response from the back-end when I hardcode the key value.

However, when I try to pass the key value dynamically in a variable by appending it to the URL, it doesn't work. I get the following error

> HTTP request failed 404

In below code, `sGrant` is the variable and it doesn't work. But if I replace the variable name with its value hard-coded in below code, for example, in the read method like this: `"/GrantMasterSet('TY560003')"`, then it works:

```js
var sGrant = this.byId("grantNbr").getValue();
var oMod = this.getOwnerComponent().getModel();
oMod.read("/GrantMasterSet('sGrant')", {
  success: function(oData) {
    var oJsonModel =  new JSONModel();
    oJsonModel.setData(oData);
    this.getView().setModel(oJsonModel);
  }.bind(this),
  error: function(oError) {
    MessageToast.show("Read Failed");
  }
});
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Create Entity Path Dynamically in UI5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46954621/how-to-create-entity-path-dynamically-in-ui5)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should concatenate the variable to the rest of the string, like this:

```
oMod.read("/GrantMasterSet('" + sGrant + "')", {
```

Or, you can use a template literal, which comes down to the same thing (notice the backtics):

```
oMod.read(`/GrantMasterSet('${sGrant}')`, {
```

Comment: Although this is correct it has the following drawbacks: 1) Depending on your key type, the URI must follow a different format. For example, when the key is a GUID, the key if totally different. If it's an integer, you won't have single quotes. 2) Template literals are not supported in IE 11 . See https://caniuse.com/#feat=template-literals

Answer (score 5):

UI5 has a method to generate the right URI for you, no matter what is the data type of the key of your entity type.

The method is `createKey` of the `sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel` class. See [its documentation](https://ui5.sap.com/#/api/sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel/methods/createKey)

Inside your controller, use the following source code.

```
onInit: function () {
    var oRouter = this.getOwnerComponent().getRouter();
    oRouter.getRoute("routeName").attachPatternMatched( this.onPatternMatched , this );
},

onPatternMatched: function(oEvent){
    var oParameters = oEvent.getParameters();
    var oArguments = oParameters.arguments; // is not a function - without ()
    var sKey = oArguments.id; // route parameter passed when using navTo

    var oDataModel = this.getView().getModel(); // v2.ODataModel

    oDataModel.metadataLoaded().then(function() {

            var sPath = oDataModel.createKey("EntitySet", {  Key: sKey });
            this.getView().bindElement("/" + sPath);

        }.bind(this)
    );

}
```

Usually this is necessary in details pages, in order to apply element binding to a page. As the `createKey` method relies on the `$metadata` of your service, you must make sure that it is already loaded in your app. This can be achieved by using method `metadataLoaded`, provided in the snippet as well.

Answer (score -2):

You should escape 'sGrant' so it can be evaluated.

It should be something like that :

```
var sGrant = this.byId("grantNbr").getValue();
var oMod = this.getOwnerComponent().getModel();

oMod.read("/GrantMasterSet("+sGrant+")", {
    success: function(oData) {
        var oJsonModel =  new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();  
        oJsonModel.setData(oData);
        this.getView().setModel(oJsonModel);
    }.bind(this),
    error: function(oError) {
        MessageToast.show("Read Failed");
    }
});
```