# Performing OData V2 methods with "Edm.DateTime" as part of primary keys

Tags: odata, sapui5

I have the problem, that I want to update a table via HTTP-request. But I always get an error-message on the Edm.DateTime attributes in the table.

> Error: Invalid URI-Segment '00:00',ValdTo=datetime'2019-04-03T00:00:00')'"}

Even the value is already converted to Edm.DateTime.

```js
valdfrom_edit = encodeURI(sap.ui.model.odata.ODataUtils.formatValue(new Date(values.ValdFrom), "Edm.DateTime"));
var update = "/ZSCORDERINGSet(Mandt='010',Vkorg='" + vkorg_Edit + "',ZzscSpSas='" + suppl_edit + "',ValdFrom=" + valdfrom_edit + ",ValdTo=" + valdto_edit + ")";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with:

```js
// ... After metadata loaded:
// Create the sPath:
const sPath = "/" + myV2ODataModel.createKey("ZSCORDERINGSet", {
  //<key>s for ZSCORDERING as described in $metadata:
  Mandt: "010",
  Vkorg: vkorg_Edit,
  ZzscSpSas: suppl_edit,
  ValdFrom: new Date(values.ValdFrom), // no need to use ODataUtils.
  ValdTo: valdto_edit
});
// Call the ODataModel API with the created sPath:
myV2ODataModel.update(sPath/*, other arguments according to the API reference ... */);
```

<sup>[API reference: `v2.ODataModel#update`](https://sdk.openui5.org/api/sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel#methods/update)</sup>

About the API `createKey`, see [How to create OData V2 entity path dynamically in UI5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46954621/how-to-create-entity-path-dynamically-in-ui5/47016070#47016070) It will create the entity path for you according to the OData specification and always in the right order.

---

**Note:** [`sap.ui.core.util.MockServer` doesn't support `Edm.DateTime` in keys](https://ui5.sap.com/#/topic/3459c372aaaa4c31ab87bb0e174adcc3).

> [...] OData features that are **not** supported by the mock server:
>
> | Feature | Status |
> | --- | --- |
> | `Edm.DateTime` keys | Unsupported |