# Bind "one to many" OData association to aggregation in UI5

Tags: data-binding, sapui5

I'm reading some data from a OData service. Within the controller, I do the following:

```js
this.getView().bindElement({
  path: "/HeaderData(key1='key1',key2='key2')",
  parameters: { expand: 'toItems' }
});
```

The data is read correctly and the model within the console looks like:

> ```
> HeaderData(key1='key1',key2='key2'): {
>   HeaderField1: "value1"
>   HeaderField2: "value2"
>   toItems: {__list: Array(2)}
> }
> ```

Now, I want to bind the entries within the `"toItems"` collection to a table.
I've tried the following but it's not working because `"toItems"` is a collection.

```xml
<Table items="{
  path: '/HeaderData',
  parameters: { expand: 'toItems' }
}">
```

This one is also not working:

```xml
<Table items="{
  path: '/HeaderData/toItems'
}">
```

How to bind the items correctly? The table could not be accessed via ID, so the binding must be within the XML view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply bind the navigation property to the aggregation:

```xml
<Table items="{toItems}">
```

Make sure to omit `/` at the beginning of the binding path since it's supposed to be resolved *relative* to the bound entity / context (that was given by `bindElement`). To learn more, see topic *[Binding Path](https://ui5.sap.com/#/topic/2888af49635949eca14fa326d04833b9)*.

The `ODataListBinding` will then send a request to the items accordingly if they're not available already.

Comment: Oh it's so easy :D. Thank you so much, it works now.

Comment: @Jacky No prob. :) Additionally, it's a good practice to make use of the API `createKey` when calling `bindElement` (especially when there are multiple keys). Here is an example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47016070/5846045

Comment: thanks for the info, I've included it in my app :).