# How to refresh previously bound entity every time user visits the page

Tags: odata, sapui5, sap-fiori

I just ran into a problem where I am not sure how to solve.

Background: I've got an App with **two views**:

- 1st one to input a number,
- 2nd one to see the details.

After the view switched to the detail view, I would call the `bindElement()` to get my data from the backend.

```js
_onRoutePatternMatched: function(oEvent) {
  // ...
  this.getView().bindElement({
    path: "/EntitySet('" + id+ "')"
  });
},
```

Problem is that the ID is quite often the same, hence, the method will call the backend only if the ID is different from the last call.

So I tried to solve the problem by using the following:

```js
this.getView().getModel().read("/EntitySet('" + id+ "')",{
  success: function(oData, response) {
    that.getView().setModel(oData, "");
  }
});
```

By this, the data is always up to date. But now the binding is a bit different.

Binding with `bindElement()`:

```js
{
  "id": "1234",
  "propety1": "abc",
  // ...
}
```

Binding with `setModel()` and `id = 1234`:

```js
{
  "EntitySet('1234')": {
    "id": "1234",
    "propety1": "abc",
    // ...
  }
}
```

For the first way, my binding looked like this:

```xml
<ObjectHeader title="{id}">
```

Now, it would have to look like this:

```xml
<ObjectHeader title="{/EntitySet('1234')/id}">
```

And here I have a problem, because the value of `id` (in this case `1234`) will always be different and so the binding won't work. I can't bind directly to the `ObjectHeader`, because I will need some properties from the model later. That is the reason I am binding to the view so that all that remain available.

My idea was to edit the binding inside the success method of the read method. I would like to delete the surrounding element. Do you have an idea, how to do this? Or even a simpler/better idea to solve my pity?

**Edit:**
I forgot to mention the `refresh` method. This would be possible, but where do I have to put it? I don't want to call the backend twice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply call the API `myODataModel.invalidateEntry(<key>)` before binding the context in order to retrieve the latest data.

```js
// after $metadata loaded..
const model = this.getOwnerComponent().getModel("odata");
const key = model.createKey(/*...*/) //See https://stackoverflow.com/a/47016070/5846045
model.invalidateEntry(key); // <-- before binding
this.getView().bindElement({
  path: "odata>/" + key,
  // ...
});
```

<sup>From https://embed.plnkr.co/b0bXJK?show=controller/Detail.controller.js,preview</sup>

---

> #### `invalidateEntry`[<sup>doc</sup>](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/api/sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel#methods/invalidateEntry)
>
> Invalidate a single entry in the model data.
>
> Mark the selected entry in the model cache as invalid. **Next time a context binding or list binding is done, the entry will be detected as invalid and will be refreshed from the server.**

Comment: it looks like that i haven't read the documentation at all... well at least i did not properly

Comment: You solution works absolutely fine and the sample is really awesome! It will take hours to understand everything in it but it will be worth it

Comment: Do you have some good tutorial/documentation for the parameters and how they work inside the `bindElement()` method? `@BoghyonHoffmann`

Comment: @OverBurned The options for the `bindElement` is dependent on the model implementation. For OData, for example, see https://ui5.sap.com/#/api/sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataContextBinding

Comment: You are awesome! Thanks a lot! I will give all of this a try in my sandbox